# With the same hardware, how is my phone getting worse performance than other phones?

Tags: gaming, smartphones

Now just wanted to make a disclaimer, I came from the iPhone side. and this is my first time in 5 years that I have used any android phones. So I have got myself a [Samsung Galaxy Z Flip 3](https://www.samsung.com/us/smartphones/galaxy-z-flip3-5g/), and when I read the device [specifications](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_z_flip3_5g-11044.php), it stated clearly that it has a Snapdragon 888 as it’s Chipset, and a Adreno 660 GPU. Now when I see these hardware, I expected the phone’s gaming performance to be excellent. But instead, when I jumped into [Genshin Impact](https://genshin.mihoyo.com/m/en/), it just gave me approximately 30-35 fps and [Call Of Duty mobile](https://www.callofduty.com/mobile) on approximately 50-60 fps when the screen is capable and is expected to display 120 fps. I understand how games are demanding and all but the fact that phones like the [Asus ROG Phone](https://rog.asus.com/phones/rog-phone-5-model/) has the exact same chipset and GPU but from review videos on Youtube the games ran with such high frame rates as if it’s on a RTX 3090 and Core i9 11th gen or something. My question is, what has caused the difference in performance between these devices and if it is possible at all, how can I tune and tweak the system to get better performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cooling. When a cpu/soc/gpu gets hot, it slows down to get less hot. The ROG phone has a bigger heatsink than the samsung galaxy Z flip 3, and the ROG phone also has active cooling vs the samsung, which has passive cooling. That makes the ROG phone's SOC less hot so it slows down less. If your hands are getting warm during a mobile gaming session, you can improve performance by putting a random casefan under the phone so it has active cooling.

Comment: that actually sounds very reasonable. my phone literally gets hot when I am only just playing a song from spotify. Looks like I will have to put a bag of ice on the back of the phone next time I do anything demanding on the phone

Comment: Cold water is actually better, thats on a bigger surface area so you get even better cooling.